# PostgreSQL: Merge times into intervals based on another column alternating value

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, intervals

I have an event data structure with `timestamp` and `action` for each device.

I`m trying to merge intervals together to get the time ranges, when the device is `OFF` while also merging overlapping intervals.

I do have a code which does this on my server and I can port it to `PL/pgSQL`. But I was wondering if this is achievable using SQL.

I know how to merge overlapping intervals when I have them, but I'm not sure how to eliminate the duplicate `OFF` or `ON` actions following each other, so that I could easily build the `OFF` ranges.

Example input:

```
           time          |    action     |
-------------------------+---------------+
2022-07-09 16:36:05.990  |      OFF
2022-07-10 09:01:28.263  |      ON
2022-07-10 12:40:42.759  |      OFF
2022-07-10 13:21:12.208  |      ON
2022-07-10 13:21:12.261  |      OFF
2022-07-10 13:21:23.225  |      ON
2022-07-10 16:47:10.393  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:45:09.033  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:45:10.439  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:45:10.441  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:48:26.640  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:48:28.070  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:49:37.502  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:49:37.503  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:49:38.892  |      OFF
2022-07-11 13:49:38.895  |      OFF
2022-07-11 15:57:09.478  |      OFF
2022-07-11 15:58:00.995  |      ON
2022-07-11 15:58:01.048  |      OFF
2022-07-11 15:58:12.055  |      ON
```

Desired output (range can be in 2 columns)

```
           range                                   |    state     |
---------------------------------------------------+---------------+
2022-07-09 16:36:05.990 - 2022-07-10 09:01:28.263  |      OFF
2022-07-10 12:40:42.759 - 2022-07-10 13:21:12.208  |      OFF
2022-07-10 13:21:12.261 - 2022-07-10 13:21:23.225  |      OFF
2022-07-10 16:47:10.393 - 2022-07-11 15:58:00.995  |      OFF
2022-07-11 15:58:01.048 - 2022-07-11 15:58:12.055  |      OFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps and islands problem.  We can use the difference in row numbers method here, along with `LEAD()` to find to the ending `ON` timestamp for each `OFF` range.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY action ORDER BY time) rn2,
              LEAD(time) OVER (ORDER BY time) lead_time
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT MIN(time)::text || ' - ' || MAX(lead_time)::text AS range,
       'OFF' AS state
FROM cte
WHERE action = 'OFF'
GROUP BY rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY MIN(time);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo